# what is configuration in @ParamConverter in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am  reading this

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

I am not able to get what does this function returns

`$configuration->getName()`

I mean the name of what

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter $configuration->getName() returns the attribute name

Answer (score 0):

If you take this as example

`@ParamConverter("article", class="AcmeArticleBundle:Comment", options={"id" = "article_id"})`

`$configuration->getName()` would return `article`

reference [DateTime Converter](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter)

Comment: so u mean the className because Comment is a clas